# Chrome opens by Selenium but shows nothing, blank page

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Whatever the url is, chrome opens but totally empty.
IDE is eclipse, using Java and Selenium.
Tried to reinstall the chromedriver, and Selenium libraries.
Need to mention that in the url bar, it is written: **data:,**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\LIOR\\Quality Assurance\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://prd.canvusapps.com/signup");
```

I am trying to open a webpage with Selenium, using eclipse.

Comment: Chrome doesn't opens a totally empty page but with `data:` in the url

Comment: What version of chrome **driver** are you using? What version of chrome **browser** are you using? The major versions must match.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you are seeing a socket error, try setting this: options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");  (I think this will be fixed in future versions of Selenium... 4.9?)  Chrome11 added a security feature which broke Chromedriver using Java versions <11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more import line

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\LIOR\\Quality 
    surance\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Add two lines of code given below

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
```

Now pass options object in ChromeDriver() constructor like given below

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("https://prd.canvusapps.com/signup");
```

Comment: These lines made the difference! Thanks!